# Can we use GoJS library offline in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, offline, diagram, gojs

Can GOJS Library be downloaded and used in a JS script  offline ?
I've tried to download the library and use it as the following code but its not working

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- use go-debug.js when developing and go.js when deploying -->
  <script src="go-debug.js"></script>
  . . .
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a problem statement. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: check there download section `https://gojs.net/latest/download.html`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either in a browser, as any of the samples show when run as a file, or in the Node.js environment.

https://gojs.net/latest/samples/index.html

https://gojs.net/latest/intro/nodeScript.html

Make sure the library file is in the same folder, if you are going to refer to it without any path.